# Why is the content of the first nav tab replaced after clicking to a different tab?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a set of Bootstrap tabs, but if I click away from the first tab to another tab and then back to the first tab, the content of the first tab is replaced with the content of the last clicked tab. I have no idea why this is happening and cannot find a solution to the problem.

I've already done a bunch of googling and can't find any solution.

```
<div class="col">
    <h3>Account Settings</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-4" id="settingsTabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="account-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#account" role="tab" aria-controls="account" aria-selected="true">Account</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="settings-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#followers" role="tab" aria-controls="followers" aria-selected="false">Followers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#following" role="tab" aria-controls="following" aria-selected="false">Following</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="settingsContent">

     <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="account" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="account-tab">
         <div class="mt-5">
             <h4>Change Username</h4>
             <form action="/account" method="POST">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newUsername" placeholder="New Username" />
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6 pb-5 border-bottom">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" name="confirmUsername" placeholder="Confirm Username" />
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mt-2" value="Save" />
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
         <div class="mt-5">
             <h4>Change Password</h4>
             <form action="/account" method="POST">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6">
                         <input type="password" class="form-control" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" />
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6 pb-5 border-bottom">
                         <input type="password" class="form-control mt-3" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mt-2" value="Save" />
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="settings-tab">
        <div>
            This is the settings tab
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="followers" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="followers-tab">
        This is the followers tab
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="following" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="following-tab">
        This is the following tab
     </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

When clicking back to the first tab, the actual content should show, not the content of the last clicked tab. This is really boggling my mind. Help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Trying with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j04avfz/) it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Its works fine, no problem found in your code

Answer (score 0):

No problem found its work correctly. By the way, if there is problem in calling or ordering CDN/Library, below is the perfect result of your need.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<div class="col">
    <h3>Account Settings</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-4" id="settingsTabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="account-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#account" role="tab" aria-controls="account" aria-selected="true">Account</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="settings-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#followers" role="tab" aria-controls="followers" aria-selected="false">Followers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#following" role="tab" aria-controls="following" aria-selected="false">Following</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="settingsContent">

     <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="account" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="account-tab">
         <div class="mt-5">
             <h4>Change Username</h4>
             <form action="/account" method="POST">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newUsername" placeholder="New Username" />
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6 pb-5 border-bottom">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" name="confirmUsername" placeholder="Confirm Username" />
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mt-2" value="Save" />
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
         <div class="mt-5">
             <h4>Change Password</h4>
             <form action="/account" method="POST">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6">
                         <input type="password" class="form-control" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" />
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6 pb-5 border-bottom">
                         <input type="password" class="form-control mt-3" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mt-2" value="Save" />
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="settings-tab">
        <div>
            This is the settings tab
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="followers" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="followers-tab">
        This is the followers tab
     </div>

     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="following" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="following-tab">
        This is the following tab
     </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```